# Review contents of arcpy.da.Walk without a for loop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I would like to review the contents of the result of running arcpy.da.Walk()

```
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(in_dir, type=type)
```

The documentation suggests running a for loop over the walk object, as in:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    # Disregard any folder named 'back_up' in creating list of rasters
    if "back_up" in dirnames:
        dirnames.remove('back_up')
    for filename in filenames:
        rasters.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

However, I would like to review the three items separately. The documentation states that the result is a tuple, so I feel like I should be able to get the values using either:

```
dirpath, dirnames, filenames = walk
```

or

```
dirpath = walk[0]
```

In the first case, I get errors "ValueError: too many values to unpack" and in the second, I get "TypeError: 'Workspace Walker object' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

How can I access the contents of the walk result without having to run a for loop over the output?

Comment: Python iterators are kinda wonky.  You need to use them as documented.

Comment: To manually increment a Python iterator, you need to use [next() - Built-in Functions - Python 3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):  `next(walk)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that perhaps you're asking the wrong question, and (depending on what the real problem is that you're trying to solve), you may even be better off using something other than 'walk'.  As @bixb0012 commented, you can use the `next()` function, but this isn't really any better than using a `for` loop.

The `walk()` function does NOT simply produce a tuple of three values.  It produces a tuple of three values FOR EACH DIRECTORY in the tree being walked.  Therefore you cannot get a separate tree for each of those three items.

So to avoid using a `for` loop, you can only do something like:

```
walker = arcpy.da.Walk("/some/path")
(root, dirs, files) = next(walker)
print dirs
print files
...
...
(root, dirs, files) = next(walker)
print dirs
print files
...
...
```

But that doesn't really have any benefits over the `for` loop method.

Ie, `walk` iterates over directories in the tree, not through three complete sets each of root/dirs/files in the whole tree.

Comment: Thank you, this is a helpful answer for the question as I posed it. Looping over `walk` results was slower than I wanted, and it seems that this is unavoidable. To get a quick list of which directories contain files of type `type` I would use `os` tools rather than ArcGIS tools in future because of the clunkiness of the results from `walk`.